# Transfer attribute and split line

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, vector, merge, conflation

I have two line dataset that represent the same roads:

- First one has very precise geometry
- Second one has an approximative geometry, but very interesting attribute.

What I want to achieve is to have the geometry of the first one and the attribute of the second one. I wish to find an automated way to do it. There are many roads and it would takes decades to do it by hand.

I prepared some examples:

At first I have this data:

[image: What I have at the beginning]

And I want to transfer the good attributes to the good geometry:

[image]

To obtain something like that:

[image]

I had a look at the [transfer attribute](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/editing/transfer-attributes.htm) in ArcMap, however, it seems that it can't split the destination geometry in order to represent all the originals attributes values.
I probably need something that first conflate the bad geometry on the good one and then split it according to the attributes.

Comment: Split good geometry into segment, spatial join bad geometry attributes to the segments, dissolve.

Comment: @BERA But how do I know where to split the good geometry? I can't do it by hand, because there are many many roads.

Comment: There are tools for splitting. Split every 1 meter or shorter if you need more precision

Comment: @BERA Are you thinking of something like the methods mentionned in [this](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-existing-features/ways-to-split-a-line-feature.htm) page? The problem is that I don't know **where** to split it. All these methods assume that you know this, or that you split it at regular interval, or percentages. In my case, I need to split it according to another line.

Comment: @BERA Ohhh I see, you mean split into very small segments, then after attribute transfer, dissolve the mini-lines that have the same attributes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72453/discussion-between-legisey-and-bera).

Comment: As far as knowing where to split the good line's geometry, you could try: take the bad geometry features, run feature vertices to points (both ends setting) http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/feature-vertices-to-points.htm and use resulting points to run Split Line at Point (with search radius specified) http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/split-line-at-point.htm.  I've not tried personally, but logic says it should help you get the good geometry split at least to prep for attribute transfer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the method proposed by @BERA and it worked pretty well.
What I did:

- Cut the "good geometry" into 10 meters segements
- Run the [Transfer Attribute](http://pro.arcgis.com/fr/pro-app/tool-reference/editing/transfer-attributes.htm) from ESRI
- Dissolve the result to reduce the number of segments

I guess that, with this method, I get about 75% of cases right. The other are not mapped. I get very few false positive.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative (more complicated, but generally more accurate) idea:

1. Use the `Split Line at Vertices` tool to chop your bad geometry into
   small discrete segments
2. Use `Generate Points Along Lines` and check `'Include End Points'` but don't specify a distance - you'll get a point for each endpoint of your segments
3. Use `Near` and check `'Location'` with that point dataset from step 2 and your good geometry to get the nearest corresponding points on your good geometry
4. Convert those `NEAR_X` and `NEAR_Y` fields to their own dataset using `Make XY Event Layer`
5. Use `Split Line At Point` with your good geometry and and the point dataset from 4

You can now transfer attributes and dissolve. This works well when your vertices have no predictable spacing but your dataset is large. Otherwise you could just use @Legisey's answer with a very small distance (something below the spatial resolution of your dataset, otherwise you risk making your dataset less accurate).